# Proving for a condition based on set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came up with this question

If A is a subset of B , then A **intersection** B = A

> If $A \subseteq B$ , then $A \cap B = A$

Can anyone please explain me how to do it?
 Thank you so much!

Comment: Elements of intersection are elements of $A$ and $B$. But we can leave out the part "and $B$", because elements of $A$ are *automatically* elements of $B$ since $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: As an aside, I think you.ahould review the difference between "I came up with this question" and things like "I came upon this question".

Answer (score 0):

If A is a subset of B, then all elements of A are found in B. So their common elements, their intersection, is exactly the A set.
An example:
A={x; y}
B={x; y; z}
A ⊆ B, because x ∈ A, x ∈ B and y ∈ A, y ∈ B (! z ∈ B, but z ∉ A, so A≠B)
A∩B={x; y}∩{x; y; z}={x; y}=A

Comment: Thank you so much Ma'am , is tis the formal proof?

Comment: You don't normally have to do a demonstration, because the final statement is obvious, but you can use it, if you need one.

Comment: oh thank you so much